# UIButton added to inputAccessoryView not detecting touches

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uibutton, inputaccessoryview

I have an `inputAccessoryView` which includes a `UIButton`, but the `UIButton` is not responding to taps (not even changing it's image). I'm not sure why. Here's my fairly simple code:

```
UIImageView *accessoryView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 60)];

UIButton *selectionModeOkButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(264, 11, 50, 46)];
[selectionModeOkButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_count_ok_unpressed"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[selectionModeOkButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_count_ok_pressed"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[selectionModeOkButton addTarget:self action:@selector(selectionModeOkButtonPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[accessoryView addSubview:selectionModeOkButton];

self.selectionModeTextField.inputAccessoryView = accessoryView;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Apple docs for `UIImageView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiimageview_class/index.html):

> A Boolean value that determines whether user events are ignored and removed from the event queue.
>
> This property is inherited from the UIView parent class. This class changes the default value of this property to NO.

This is telling you that, by default, new `UIImageView`s have `userInteractionEnabled` set to `NO`. So, add this line:

```
accessoryView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

---

For more information on how exactly `userInteractionEnabled` works, check out the entry for that property in the [Apple docs for `UIView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/userInteractionEnabled) (the class from which that property is inherited).